# multiple nested groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-12',6: '2016-10-12',7: '2016-10-12',8: '2016-10-12',9: '2016-10-12'}, 'Stock': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H',8: 'I', 9:'J'}, 'Sector': {0: 0,1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:1, 9:1}, 'Segment': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6:2,7:2,8:3,9:3}, 'Range': {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 6, 6:0, 7:23, 8:5, 9:5}})
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

I want to add the following columns:

- 'Date_Range_Avg': average of 'Range' grouped by Date
- 'Date_Sector_Range_Avg': average of 'Range' grouped by Date and Sector
- 'Date_Segment_Range_Avg': average of 'Range' grouped by Date and Segment

This would be the output:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-12',6: '2016-10-12',7: '2016-10-12',8: '2016-10-12',9: '2016-10-12'}, 'Stock': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H',8: 'I', 9:'J'}, 'Sector': {0: 0,1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:1, 9:1}, 'Segment': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6:2,7:2,8:3,9:3}, 'Range': {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 6, 6:0, 7:23, 8:5, 9:5}, 'Date_Range_Avg':{0: 1.6, 1: 1.6, 2: 1.6, 3: 1.6, 4: 1.6, 5: 7.8, 6: 7.8, 7: 7.8, 8:7.8, 9: 7.8}, 'Date_Sector_Range_Avg':{0: 2.5, 1: 2.5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 9.67, 6: 9.67, 7: 9.67, 8: 9.67, 9: 9.67}, 'Date_Segment_Range_Avg':{0: 5, 1: 0.75, 2: 0.75, 3: 0.75, 4: 0.75, 5: 6, 6: 11.5, 7: 11.5, 8: 5, 9: 5}})
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Note I have rounded some of the values - but this rounding is not essential for the question I have (please feel free to not round)

I'm aware that I can do each of these groupings separately but it strikes me as inefficient (my dataset contains millions of rows)

Essentially, I would like to first do a grouping by `Date` and then re-use it to do the two more fine-grained groupings by `Date and Segment` and by `Date and Sector`.

How to do this?

My initial hunch is to go like this:

```
day_groups = df.groupby("Date")
df['Date_Range_Avg'] = day_groups['Range'].transform('mean')
```

and then to re-use `day_groups` to do the 2 more fine-grained groupbys like this:

```
df['Date_Sector_Range_Avg'] = day_groups.groupby('Segment')[Range].transform('mean')
```

Which doesn't work as you get:

'AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`groupby` runs really fast when the aggregate function is vectorized. If you are worried about performance, try it out first to see if it's the real bottleneck in your program.

You can create temporary data frames holding the result of each `groupby`, then successively `merge` them with `df`:

```py
group_bys = {
    "Date_Range_Avg": ["Date"],
    "Date_Sector_Range_Avg": ["Date", "Sector"],
    "Date_Segment_Range_Avg": ["Date", "Segment"]
}

tmp = [
    df.groupby(columns)["Range"].mean().to_frame(key)
    for key, columns in group_bys.items()
]

result = df
for t in tmp:
    result = result.merge(t, left_on=t.index.names, right_index=True)
```

Result:

```
         Date Stock  Sector  Segment  Range  Date_Range_Avg  Date_Sector_Range_Avg  Date_Segment_Range_Avg
0  2016-10-11     A       0        0      5             1.6               2.500000                    5.00
1  2016-10-11     B       0        1      0             1.6               2.500000                    0.75
2  2016-10-11     C       1        1      1             1.6               1.000000                    0.75
3  2016-10-11     D       1        1      0             1.6               1.000000                    0.75
4  2016-10-11     E       1        1      2             1.6               1.000000                    0.75
5  2016-10-12     F       0        1      6             7.8               9.666667                    6.00
6  2016-10-12     G       0        2      0             7.8               9.666667                   11.50
7  2016-10-12     H       0        2     23             7.8               9.666667                   11.50
8  2016-10-12     I       1        3      5             7.8               5.000000                    5.00
9  2016-10-12     J       1        3      5             7.8               5.000000                    5.00
```

Another option is to use `transform`, and avoid the multiple merges:

```py
# reusing your code
group_bys = {
         "Date_Range_Avg": ["Date"],
         "Date_Sector_Range_Avg": ["Date", "Sector"],
         "Date_Segment_Range_Avg": ["Date", "Segment"]
     }
    
     tmp = {key : df.groupby(columns)["Range"].transform('mean')
         for key, columns in group_bys.items()
     }

df.assign(**tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick & informative reply! I wanted to re-use the grouping by Date. In your reply all 3 groupbys are done in isolation from each other. My gut feeling is that there can be a more efficient way of doing it (but I might be wrong!)

Comment: You have to do 3 groupbys regardless. There is no way to reuse `(Date, Sector)` and `(Date, Segment)`as their grouping keys are completely different. You *may* be able to "roll-up" one of them to get the result for `Date` but it may not be faster. Try it, benchmark it and evaluate if you have a real bottleneck. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: added an option to your code, feel free to delete ... just another option without the multiple merges

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks. it was a good solution

Comment: @CodeDifferent Agree on the premature optimisation. However, I think you misunderstood me - I want to re-use the  `Date` groupby to do 2 more fine-grained groupbys: `Date, Segment` and `Date, Sector`. This should be possible, no?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine it's possible, but I wouldn't expect it to be performant as you'd have to do in "inner" groupby within each group individually. operating on indexes might squeeze out some more performance.